# Loading Page Specific CSS in Sitecore

Tags: presentation, css

We are using Sitecore 8.2 and we have around 10-15 Page templates and all the CSS is bundled in a Global CSS and over the years the CSS file has grown tremendously
resulting in below issues:

1. We are loading lot of unused CSS which not be required for all pages for example Product & Article page CSS may not be required for Home Page & Vice versa.
2. This has resulted in lot of performance issues.

Is there a module or Utility which can load only Required CSS for a page considering the fact we have single Layout for the pages.

Comment: 1) what is the problem with it? in general it should not be a problem to load unused CSS
2) how big is your CSS? do you have client side caching enabled for static files (CSS, JS)?

Comment: its actually around 10 MB and it's cached & Bundled we actually want to load only used CSS on a page

Comment: 10 MB of bundled CSS is very huge, what will be the size of a beautified CSS in this case? with regards to your question, I think you should have separate files for each page template type and add current item template condition to render the CSS specific to that page type.

Comment: If you have 10MB of CSS, then you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Optimize your CSS file, and I don't just mean minify it, there are underlying architectural problems with a CSS file that big and they should be addressed. Especially if you only have 10-15 page templates.